# Парсинг с бесконечным скроллингом с помощью Selenium, python

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, beautiful-soup, веб-скрейпинг

Пытаюсь спарсить сайт instajen, где имеется бесконечный скролинг. Однако, получается спарсить только первый 30 постов из 6000, а дальше код больше страницу не скролит. Подскажите, что поменять. Ссылка на сайт "https://instajet.in/catalog"

```
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
url = 'https://instajet.in/catalog'
driver.get(url)

previous_height = driver.execute_script('return document.body.scrollHeight')

while True:
    driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight );')
    sleep(2)

    new_height = driver.execute_script('return document.body.scrollHeight')
    if new_height == previous_height:
           break
    previous_height = new_height


soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")
posts = soup.find_all('div', class_='catalog-cards')

for post in posts:
    title = post.find('div', class_='text').text
    print(title)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests

headers = {'Ch-locale': 'ru'}
params = {
    'exclude_blacklisted': 'true',
    'exclusives': 'false',
    'discounts': 'false',
    'favorites': 'false',
    'trusted': 'false',
    'new': 'false',
    'sort_asc': 'false',
    'sort_by': 'rating',
    'limit': '6699',
    'offset': '0',
}
response = requests.get('https://api.instajet.io/api/v1/accounts/catalog', params=params, headers=headers)
ss = response.json()
print(ss['total'])
print(len(ss['accounts']))
print(ss['accounts'][0]['name'])
print(ss['accounts'][-1]['name'])

# 6699
# 6699
# Mammy_margosha
# photo_maznichenochka
```